# How to see all the changes by one developer in ClearCase?

Tags: version-control, clearcase

I am trying  to look into a project and see all the changes that has been done by a specific developer. Is this possible with ClearCase?

(I only have access to the repository through ClearTeam Explorer, I don't have command line access to it. I appreciate if you keep that in mind as well answering my question)

Answer (score 1):

You can try and use the [ClearTeam Navigator view](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v8m0r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.ccrc.help.doc/topics/u_tree_view.htm) in order to display all UCM activities for a given stream: that should be enough to sort those by author and see that way all changes done were by a specific user.
Selecting an activity would allow you to see its change set (list of versions created and recorded for said activity).